# Presenting data from database without multiplying specific field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this in database:
[image]

and I want to display it like this:

> date1 worktime UserName1
>   date2 worktime 
>   date3 worktime 
>   date1 worktime UserName2
>   date2 worktime 
>   date3 worktime

I've cereated a `Model`:

```
[Table("Work_Hours")]
public class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan WorkTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class UserDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And tried to solve my problem with `ViewModel`:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public LinkedList<TimeSpan> WorkTime { get ; set;}
    public LinkedList<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know how add only one object and list of `WorkTime` and `Date` to new list of viewmodels for one specific `UserName` from list of `models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq already has this built in. Given:

```
IEnumerable<User> data=...; // input from somewhere
```

You can do:

```
var groups=data.GroupBy(w=>w.UserName); // type is IGrouping<string, User>
```

Enumerating this object will give you a `Key` property which is the username, once for each item, then enumerating this returning object again will give you every item that has the specified username.